# writing down likelihood for dynamic state space model?

Tags: probability, bayesian, stochastic-processes, hierarchical-bayesian, state-space-models

I have a discrete-time state space model where observations depend on a latent rate $X$. The prior on the rate is $X \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_x, \sigma_x)$. Each observation $Y_t$ is generated using the rate and the previous observation $Y_{t-1}$:

$Y_t = Y_{t-1} + Y_{t-1}X$

where $Y_0 \sim \mathrm{Normal}(\mu_y, \sigma_y)$. The rate $X$ could be time-dependent as well but for simplicity assume there is a single rate $X$ fixed across time. I want to find $P(X \mid Y_1,...,Y_t)$. The question is: What is the likelihood function of $Y_t$ given $X$ and $Y_{t-1}$, i.e. $P(Y_t \mid Y_{t-1}, X)$?

**update:**

as @jbowman said $P(Y_t \mid Y_{t-1}, X)$ is degenerate since $Y_t$ is completely determined by $Y_{t-1}, X$.

more about the problem to respond to @peuhp: my data are observations $Y_1,...,Y_n$, of levels of a material through (discrete) time. the rate of change of the material ($R$) is the parameter I want to estimate. $R$ constrains $Y$ in a deterministic way, so the probability is degenerate. is there a way to formulate this more naturally as a hierarchical bayesian model, to avoid degenerate probability distributions?

Comment: Since $Y_{t-1}$ is fixed, $P(Y_t | Y_{t-1})$ is just a Normal distribution with mean $Y_{t-1}(1 + \mu_x)$ and standard deviation $Y_{t-1}\sigma_x$.  If you condition on $X$ also, as suggested by your notation, then there's no randomness left and $Y_t$ has a degenerate distribution at the point $Y_{t-1}(1 + X)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comment there is no randomness in your model of X|Y_1\ldots Y_t.  Indeed, following your model:
$$
X=\frac{Y_{i}}{Y_{i-1}}-1 \mbox{,    for all i>2}
$$
I guess that this is not what your are trying to express and that you rethink your model.
Notice that even if $X$ is time dependant you have the same ($
X_i=\frac{Y_{i}}{Y_{i-1}}-1 \mbox{,    for all i>2}
$)

Mayabe something closer to what you expecvt will be: something like a physical model
$$
Y_t=Y_{t-1} \cdot X + Y_{t-1}
$$
coupled to an observation model:
$$
O_t=Y_t + \epsilon_t
$$
where $\epsilon_t$ is the measurement error and e.g $\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

In such a case your observation are the $O_t$ and it makes sense to compute $p(X|0_{1:t})$.

Alternatively, you can consider that your uncertainty is on your physical model and in such a case:
$$
Y_t=Y_{t-1} \cdot X + Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t,physic}
$$

Finally both appraoch can be combined leading to a typical hidden markov model.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i updated my question to respond to your point. is there a better way to write down a model for the rate?

Comment: @mvd I update for some hints. Hope it helps.